# Gvim fold toggle using mouse

Tags: vim, mouse, folding

Is it possible to open and close folds in Gvim using mouse clicks ?

Say double click opens and closes folds ?

Comment: Google said you can program it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683849/mouse-input-in-gvim

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was what I was looking for

```
:noremap <2-LeftMouse> za
```

Toggles folds with mouse double click

Or may be triple click to avoid conflicting with text selecting command of vim

```
:noremap <3-LeftMouse> za
```

Answer (score 11):

In the fold column (e.g. `:set foldcolumn=4`), you can open / close folds by (single-)clicking on the signs; this works out-of-the-box.

I use a mapping similar to the one in your answer that just opens folds, but otherwise maintains the default doubleclick behavior:

```
" <2-LeftMouse>     Open fold, or select word or % match.
nnoremap <expr> <2-LeftMouse> foldclosed(line('.')) == -1 ? "\<2-LeftMouse>" : 'zo'
```

Comment: I feel so dumb now. :-P I didn't know that this exists and works out of the box, at least 10 years after it existed. Thank you. (P.S. For anyone that stumbles on this answer, it works for terminal vim as well, if you enable mouse support.)